# Como restringir um set de uma propriedade?

Tags: c#, .net, propriedade

Tenho a seguinte propriedade em minha classe:

```
public char Naipe { get; set; }
```

Esta propriedade só pode receber um dos seguintes valores:

```
(char)9824 (Espada)

(char)9827 (Paus)

(char)9829 (Copas)

(char)9830 (Ouro)
```

Estas são codificações decimais Unicode e representam cada naipe de um baralho.

Como limitar esta propriedade de forma a ser capaz de receber apenas estes valores?

Comment: Por sintaxe não é possível fazer isso, mas através duma gambiarra...

Comment: Alguma resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Answer (score 5):

*Gambi alert*

Use uma enumeração:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static Naipe Naipe { get; set; }
    public static void Main() {
        Naipe = Naipe.Copas;
        WriteLine($"{(char)Naipe.Espada} {(char)Naipe.Paus} {(char)Naipe.Copas} {(char)Naipe.Ouro} {(char)Naipe}");
    }
}

public enum Naipe { Espada = 9824, Paus = 9827, Copas = 9829, Ouro }
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Qkd501). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dS7Xok). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Enum/Stringfy.cs).

Não que seja garantido, mas é quase, dá para contornar, mas não é o procedimento padrão. Se quer garantir mesmo teria que incluir uma validação na propriedade, mas acho desnecessário, porque só será feito errado se a pessoa forçar. Sou contra se prevenir de programador teimoso, a prevenção é boa para evitar acidentes.

Isto não é o mais correto, mas funciona bem. A solução alternativa seria cria um atributo em cada membro da enumeração com o caractere, não compensa.

Outra forma seria criar uma estrutura com as opções e fazer a validação nela, assim é garantido que nunca será outra coisa. E pode facilmente associar a constante com o caractere Unicode. Não acho necessário, mas é melhor que validar na propriedade.

Answer (score 4):

Outra forma de fazer é expandir a propriedade e aplicar sua lógica

```
private char[] naipesPermitidos = new char[] {(char)9824, (char)9827, ...};
private char naipe;
public char Naipe {
    get {
        return naipe;
    }
    set {
        if (naipesPermitidos.Contains(value)) {
            naipe = value; // troca o valor
        } else {
            // e o que fazer quando não for um valor permitido?
        }
    }
}
```