# Propriedades do C# para quem conhece Java

Tags: java, c#, característica-linguagem, sintaxe, propriedade

O que um programador Java precisa saber de básico sobre propriedades (*properties*) a fim de ler código escrito em C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Propriedade é só um *syntax sugar* para os métodos *getter* e *setter* que costuma-se usar em Java e outras linguagens. Então você escreve o acesso no código como se fosse um campo, mas na verdade está acessando um dos métodos de acesso para pegar ou mudar o valor de um campo, provavelmente privado.

Ela pode fazer mais que isso (ter a lógica que achar melhor, como pode em Java) ou pode não usar um campo para fazer sua operação.

Na minha opinião fica mais legível e mais elegante, além disso dá um entendimento melhor para que serve um *getter* e *setter*, e facilita a opção. Há abusos, nem tudo deveria ser uma propriedade, assim como abusam de *getters* e *setters* onde não deve.

Quase tudo já foi respondido antes. Acho que pode começar por [Como funcionam as propriedades no C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156804/101).

Depois pode ver [quando usar um método e não uma propriedade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15467/101). E [quando usar uma variável no lugar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/133924/101). Mais em [Campo público X propriedade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/324099/101).

[Ela pode ser inicializada nominalmente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/126348/101).

[Há restrições](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/418619/101), mas [pode fazer herança](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/421706/101). Também pode ser usada de [forma estática](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/93033/101).

Ela [pode ser declarada em interface normalmente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89894/101), mas precisaria ser concretizada na classe que implementa a interface.

Pode ser interessante saber que [o `set` pode ter outra visibilidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/263457/101).

Nas próximas versões poderá até permitir apenas que seja feita uma inicialização, mas não deixa mudar depois, o que pode evitar a criação de um construtor se não quiser fazer nada extra além da inicialização de seus membros e não precisa de uma ordem específica.

[A inicialização já pode ser feita na propriedade e não no construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108516/101), pelo menos não de forma explícita (na verdade toda inicialização sempre é feita no construtor, não tem como executar algoritmos fora de um método, então ele é obrigatório e o compilador cria um com as inicializações necessárias para você.

Veja como ela simplifica a declaração em [Por que existe as auto properties no C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/405783/101). Outra forma em [Como se utilizar propriedade expandida no C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/263498/101).

Ela [pode ser usada até como indexador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/249945/101) e substituir o método `get()` (e eventualmente um `set()`) do elemento de classes que são coleções.

Pode-se ver algumas questões internas de como ela funciona:

- [O que seria esse "k_BackingField"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/306914/101)
- [Propriedade com set privado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/274008/101)
- [Como a compilação gera uma propriedade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/222044/101)
- [Uma propriedade ocupa espaço no objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203908/101)

Enfim, dá para falar de muita coisa, eu [respondi sobre isso em diversas perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+propriedade).

Answer (score 3):

Property eh um tipo que tem o getter e setter incorporado nele. Inves de criar um getter e setter publicos em uma classe pra acessar/alterar tipos privados, voce cria um property.

```
public class Carro
{
   public string Nome
   {
      get;
      set;
   }

   public Carro( string nome )
   {
       Nome = nome;
   }

}

var meuCarro = new Carro( "Model S" ); 
Console.Write( meuCarro.Nome ) // vai imprimir "Model S"

// mudando o valor do property, em outras linguages de programacao voce usaria o methodo "set()" explicitamente 
meuCarro.Nome = "Model 3"
```

Voce pode tambem colocar logica dentro do getter e setter de um property em C#, entao o valor que voce esta acessando ou modificando pode estar sendo alterado no processo.

Comment: não entendi por que a saída será "bmw"

Comment: @CaioHenriqueReblin erro, originalmente tinha colocado “bmw”, troquei no código mas não no comentário! Obrigada pela observação