# (Sobre encapsulamento) De quem estou protegendo meu programa(Atributos)?

Tags: c#

Entendi que atributos devem ser privados e alterados por métodos da própria classe, que a classe é responsável por altera-los. Mas de quem estou protegendo eles? Se uma classe quiser altera-los não vai simplesmente Instanciar um objeto do tipo da classe e usar os métodos get/set do mesmo jeito? então porque não deixa-los public? Quem pode altera-los é só quem tem acesso ao código certo?.

Não que eu vá deixa-los "public" já que fui ensinado a deixa-los "private" ou "protected" irei deixar de acordo com as regras, mas não entendo de quem estou protegendo eles além de mim?  Só uma reflexão!

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 3):

Se isso fosse verdade então eles já seriam assim, a linguagem não te obrigaria fazer na mão. Você agora está aprendendo que quase toda informação na internet está errada, de uma forma ou de outra. [Outra que ensinam errado também](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).

Você protege de você mesmo e outras pessoas que vão mexer nisso.

Em C# não se usa métodos *getter/setter*, [usa-se propriedades](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/133924/101). Pode [ver mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/447139/101).

> Quem pode altera-los é só quem tem acesso ao código certo?.

Os campos privados? Se for isso, sim em condições normais. Dá para alterar sem o código fonte, mas não é para fazer isso, só porque pode, com algum trabalho, não quer dizer que você deva fazê-lo. é protegido porque é ruim mexer.

A proteção não é sobre segurança, é só para mostrar claramente que não deve fazer.

> Não que eu vá deixa-los "public" já que fui ensinado a deixa-los "private" ou "protected" irei deixar de acordo com as regras

Isso não é ensino, é adestramento.

Você protege algo que deseja fazer o que quiser no futuro. Quando coloca algo público é um contrato que você tem com o público, você tem que garantir que sempre vai funcionar igual. Você pode garantir isso? Estão está ok. Se acha que pode mudar no futuro, é melhor ter alguma proteção.

Se você colocar um campo privado e ter propriedade (ou par de métodos), se quiser acabar com ele, ou mudar o comportamento, pode fazer sem mudar o contrato público, no geral. Mas tem casos que pode não ficar bom nem isso. Pode começar responder algo que não era o que acontecia antes, então funciona, mas não do jeito esperado. Não é tão simples, mas ajuda. Isso é o que se chama [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101).

Veja mais: [Métodos e propriedades em C# - vantagens e desvantagens](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15467/101). Só quando entender completamente o funcionamento e tiver experiência poderá fazer certo, enquanto isso fará errado, mesmo que funcione, porque está só repetindo o que te mandaram fazer. Também: [Métodos Getters e Setters](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212300/101)

Comment: Entendo, eu só estava tentando entender quando o professor falava em proteger o programa, levei isso como uma boa pratica em programação, pelo que entendi até agora campos privados seriam aqueles onde só a própria classe deve alterar podendo se utilizar logicas ou não. Quando usei os métodos Get\Set como exemplo foi porque ainda não havia estudado propriedades.

Answer (score -4):

O encapsulamento serve para você abstrair o funcionamento interno da classe para quem está de fora. É um pilar da Programação Orientada a Objetos e várias linguagens usam esse paradigma.

Isso evita que quem não conheça o funcionamento interno da classe altere valores que ocasionarão num comportamento não planejado. Serve para proteger até de você mesmo futuramente, afinal quando o sistema cresce não dá para ter tudo na cabeça todos os detalhes de cada uma das classes, então você oculta aquilo que fica dentro do escopo de funcionamento interno da classe.